# Extending Propel to emulate database functions

Tags: activerecord, orm, propel

I need to translate an application from MySQL to SQL Server.

There are many hard-coded queries involving MySQL database functions like **NOW()**, **LCASE()**, **MATCH() AGAINST()**, that has equivalent in SQL Server, but with a different syntax and structure.

I choose **Propel** because it seems to be easy-to-use.

I'm looking for a way to emulate database functions like **NOW()** *{MySQL}* and **GETDATE()** *{SQL Server}* by extending Propel classes.

I think something like this:

```
$result = Function::NOW(); // MySQL
$result = Function::GETDATE(); // SQL Server
```

When the function accepts parameters, like **LCASE()** *{MySQL}* or **LOWER()** *{SQL Server}*, it could be like this:

```
$table = new MyTable();
$result = Function::LCASE($table->getName()); // MySQL
$result = Function::LOWER($table->getName()); // SQL Server
```

or

```
$table = new MyTable();
$result = Function::MD5($table->getPassword()); // MySQL
$result = Function::HASHBYTES('MD5', $table->getPassword()); // SQL Server
```

The perfect solution would be if I can create equivalence between two functions with the same purpose from different databases (MySQL and SQL Server).

So, instead of using **Function::HASHBYTES()** in my PHP code, I could always use **Function::MD5()**, because it is more simple, and when my application is connected to a SQL Server Database, internally, *HASHBYTES()* is invoked.

Comment: So you need someting to abstract database function using Propel. But, is it not the role of Propel? What you want is add extract feature to [this class](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/master/runtime/lib/adapter/DBMSSQL.php)?

Comment: I don't see a question here... what is it? Sounds like you have a plan (although I'm not exactly sure why you need the `Function::ETCETC()` pieces at all versus using PHP functions.

Comment: There is no class named "Function" in Propel, it is only an example what I think could be useful.

I guess Propel does not abstract database functions, if you need them, you pass inside single quotes 'COUNT(fieldname)', like plain queries. Applications are commonly complex, if you need more sophisticated queries, even with Propel, you are required to use hard-coded pieces of queries.

Comment: Take a see in this code (below) from Propel website: http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html

    $nbComments = ArticleQuery::create()
      ->join('Comment')
      ->withColumn('count(Comment.ID)', 'nbComments')
      ->groupBy('Article.Title')
      ->select(array('Article.Title', 'nbComments'))
      ->find();

Look at the function "count()". If this function was "now()", I would need to rewrite it to "getdate()" when migrating my application to SQL Server.

Comment: The main differences among databases are database functions. If I can abstract them, I can easily write an Application for MySQL and migrate to another database like SQL Server or Oracle with no need to touch source code (rewrite queries).

About where the question is, I am newbie on Propel, I don't know almost anything about it. What I need is a way to abstract database functions, but I don't know how can I do it in Propel.